# What is the purpose of the cancellationToken parameter in Task.FromCanceled?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

Is there any reason not to call this method as:

```
var task = Task.FromCanceled(new CancellationToken(true));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canceled tasks raise a `TaskCanceledException` if you try to await the task (or throw a `AggragateException` with the `TaskCanceledExcption` as the inner exception if you get the `.Result` or call `.Wait()`). One of the properties of that exception is [the CancelationToken that caused the cancellation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operationcanceledexception.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx), the token passed in to the constructor is assigned to the property of that exception.

If your code does not care about the token in the exception raised from the task then there is no reason not to just do what you did in your example.

Comment: So I can assume equity on a token works such that : isFromSource = operationCanceledException.CancellationToken == cancellationTokenSource.Token;